# How to convert MS SQL Date or DateTime to OADate?

Tags: sql-server, excel, database, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I know we can convert an OADateTime (the number format sometimes excel presents us with instead of datetime) to a valid DateTime like below -

`SELECT CAST(43982 AS datetime) -2`

which results in 2020-05-31 00:00:00.000.

But how do we convert a DateTime to OADateTime in MS SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way would be to subtract the OADate epoch from a given date, e.g.:

```sql
declare @OADateEpoch date = convert(date, '1899-12-30', 126);
declare @yourDateTime datetime = convert(date, '2020-05-31T00:00:00.000', 126);
select datediff(dd, @OADateEpoch, @yourDateTime);
```

Which returns `43982`.

Comment: But how do we convert a DateTime to OADateTime? for example '2020-12-04T15:15:00.000' ?